# How to extract logs from a timestamp till the end of the file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, extract

I want to extract logs from a log file, say the file name is todayslog.log

My logs are in the following format:

```
[12/21/16 4:21:00:083 MST] blah blah 1
[12/21/16 4:22:00:102 MST] blah blah 2
[12/21/16 4:23:00:128 MST] blah blah 3
```

I want to extract logs from the first occurrence of say "12/21/16 4:21:00:083 MST" till the end of file.

I have tried the following codes but it isn't working because of the '/' present in my date.

```
sed -e '/12/21/16 1:30:54:663/,$p' todayslog.log
sed -n '/12/21/16 4:21:00:028/,/12/21/16 4:21:00:128/p' todayslog.log
```

Comment: Reading the sed documentation helps where injecting the escaping backslash marking a literal slash via `\/` does not suffice ... HTH

Comment: Doesn't `sed -n -e '@12/21/16 1:30:54@,$p' file` solve your problem? On some systems, you might need `\@12...@'`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the below technique

```
$ cat 41265401 # this is my file with data
[12/21/16 4:21:00:083 MST] blah blah 1
[12/21/16 4:22:00:102 MST] blah blah 2
[12/21/16 4:23:00:128 MST] blah blah 3
[12/21/16 6:24:00:128 MST] blah blah 6
[12/21/16 8:29:00:101 MST] blah blah 8
bla bla
bla bla

$ cat 41265401.sh 
#!/bin/bash
find_me="12/21/16 4:23:00:128 MST" # you can also pass the string as argument
start_pos=$(grep -nm1 "$find_me" 41265401)
start_pos=${start_pos%%:*} # Shell param expansion, see [1]
awk -v start_pos="$start_pos" 'FNR>=start_pos' 41265401 > result

$ ./41265401.sh # script in action

$ cat result  # from first match till end
[12/21/16 4:23:00:128 MST] blah blah 3
[12/21/16 6:24:00:128 MST] blah blah 6
[12/21/16 8:29:00:101 MST] blah blah 8
bla bla
bla bla
```

---

**References**

<sup>**[1]** : [**Shell Param expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

there's also [dategrep](https://github.com/mdom/dategrep), a small tool that allows one to filter entries by date.
Something like:

```
dategrep --start "12/21/16 4:21:00" --format "%x %X" todayslog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it comes `sed` with:

```
sed -n '/12\/21\/16 4:21:00:083 MST/ {:end; p; n; b end}'
```